# Key error en django al usar kwargs.pop

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

os agradecería la ayuda, parece que estoy bloqueado con esto, y no debería ser complicado.

Tengo una función en `views.py` que instancia un formulario del siguiente modo:

```
form = BusquedaPresenciaForm(initial={'fecha_inicio': datetime.date.today(), 'fecha_fin': datetime.date.today()}, form_kwargs={'usuario_actual': request.user.id})
```

En `forms.py` tengo el siguiente formulario

```
class BusquedaPresenciaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        usuario_actual = kwargs.pop('usuario_actual')
        super(BusquedaPresenciaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['usuario'].queryset = Coordinacion.objects.filter(coordinador=usuario_actual.id)
```

Se trata de que en un campo del formulario nos filtre un `<select>` del campo usuario del formulario, según el usuario actual.

El error que me está devolviendo es:

```
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'usuario_actual'
```

En la línea:

```
usuario_actual = kwargs.pop('usuario_actual')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he replanteado un poquito y lo he puesto a funcionar los cambios son cuando se instancia el formulario en views.py

```
form = BusquedaPresenciaForm(initial={'fecha_inicio': datetime.date.today(), 'fecha_fin': datetime.date.today()}, usuario_actual=request.user)
```

Parece que no es necesario usar "form_kwargs=" para pasar valores al formulario, leí algo relativo a esto en la documentación y parece ser que lo entendí de forma erronea.

Comment: Si, en python no necesitas eso si lo recibes desde el metodo __init__(), quizás lo leiste en la documentacion de los formsets, donde el formset si tiene una llave para los kwargs de los formularios